# Sort a column by number of identical occurrences - using awk, sort, tr or uniq?

Tags: unix, sorting, awk, tr, uniq

Let's say I have some tab-separated data:

```
Peter   5
Joe     8
Peter   7
Peter   8
Joe     4
Laura   3
```

And I want to sort it by the number of times a name occurs in the first column (max to min)
So we'd have Peter (3 occurrences) Joe (2 occurrences) and Laura (1 occurrence).

```
Peter   5
Peter   7
Peter   8
Joe     8
Joe     4
Laura   3
```

It only needs sorted by the first column, not the second. I've been reading sort's documentation, and I don't think it has the functionality. Anyone have an easy method?

Comment: does it mean 2nd column has nothing to do with this question?

Comment: correct. The data in that column just needs to stay in order with the given name.

Comment: Does it matter that in the result set, Peter's entries are listed in ascending order of column 2 values, but Joe's are listed in reverse order?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: No - the OP wants to sort descending on occurrence of column one, keeping the order of column two as they appear in the file. Presumably, the order of duplicate occurrences (of column one) doesn't matter, just as long as column two maintains the order with the given name. See the OP's comment above. HTH.

Comment: For your comment on steve's solution, it would have been useful to mention the file size in the question. Perhaps there is some limit to the amount of data that can be sorted in the a array? What is the range that you have on matches? Three max? 50 max? What?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not sexy but works for your example:

```
 awk  'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}{ print a[$1],$0}' file file|sort -nr|sed -r 's/[0-9]* //'
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  cat n.txt
Peter   5
Joe     8
Peter   7
Peter   8
Joe     4
Laura   3

kent$  awk  'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}{ print a[$1],$0}' n.txt n.txt|sort -nr|sed -r 's/[0-9]* //'
Peter   8
Peter   7
Peter   5
Joe     8
Joe     4
Laura   3
```

Comment: The data (field 2) needs to stay in order as per the comments below the question.

Comment: The `-r` option is unnecessary; the regex used is a basic `sed` regex.

Comment: @ChrisJ.Vargo yes, you can just remove the '-r' option. it should work too.

Comment: Wow. I just ran this on my BSD box and this works brilliantly. Moreover, very efficient on a list of 38 million rows. Kent, thank you so much!

Comment: @ChrisJ.Vargo glad to help. it ran fast because you got powerful cpus. :) there is no hack algorithm in my codes

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
for person in $(awk '{print $1}' file.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -dnr | awk '{print $2}');
do grep -e "^$person[[:space:]]" file.txt;
done
```

Comment: So, to make the example data simple, I didn't mention that names from $1 occasionally are mentioned in $2. This could be avoided in your code by adding a /t after the $person. Do you think: grep '$person\| ' would work?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="\t"
}

{
    c[$1]++
    r[$1] = (r[$1] ? r[$1] ORS : "") $0
}

END {

    for (i in c) {
        a[c[i],i] = i
    }

    n = asorti(a)

    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        split(a[i], b, SUBSEP)
        x[++j] = b[2]
    }

    for (i=n;i>=1;i--) {
        print r[x[i]]
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Peter   5
Peter   7
Peter   8
Joe     8
Joe     4
Laura   3
```

Comment: Wow. Steve, this is the second question you've answered of mine in as many days. What resources do you recommend to learn scripting like this? FYI: I'm running this on a large text file. I get this error: awk: calling undefined function asorti
 input record number 38823587, file input.txt
 source line number 16

Comment: @ChrisJ.Vargo: It looks like I should have researched some of your previous questions. From what I can see, it looks like you're using `BSD/OSX awk` which unfortunately doesn't support the array sorting functions (`asort` and `asorti`) that are available when using `GNU awk`. I highly recommend installing and using GNU utilities; particular `GNU awk` and `GNU sed` - you'll only save yourself a lot of time and hassle in the future. Re resources: SO is probably the best place for learning algorithm development using `awk`. TBH, I haven't come across a better resource. Learn by doing. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

That's a surprisingly hard sort criterion.  This code works, but it is pretty ugly:

```
data=${1:-data}
awk '{ print $1 }' $data |
sort |
uniq -c |
sort -k2 |
join -1 2 -2 2 -o 1.1,2.1,2.2,2.3 - <(awk '{ print NR, $0 }' $data | sort -k2) |
sort -k1,1nr -k3,3 -k2n |
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} { print $3, $4 }'
```

It assumes `bash` 4.x for 'process substitution' but doesn't use any sorting built into `awk` (that's a GNU extension compared with POSIX `awk`).  With an explicit temporary file, it can be made to work in shells without process substitution.

```
data=${1:-data}                  # File named on command line, or uses name 'data'
awk '{ print $1 }' $data |       # List of names
sort |                           # Sorted list of names
uniq -c |                        # Count occurrences of each name
sort -k2 |                       # Sort in name order
join -1 2 -2 2 -o 1.1,2.1,2.2,2.3 - <(awk '{ print NR, $0 }' $data | sort -k2) |
# The process substitution numbers each record in sequence and sorts in name order
# The join matches the names (column 2) and outputs the frequency, record number, name, value
sort -k1,1nr -k3,3 -k2n |        # Sort on frequency reversed, name, original line number
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} { print $3, $4 }'   # Print name and value
```

Using GNU `awk` with a built-in sort, or Perl or Python, is probably better than this.

For the original data, the output is:

```
Peter   5
Peter   7
Peter   8
Joe     8
Joe     4
Laura   3
```

Given this extended version of the data:

```
Peter   5
Joe     8
Peter   7
Peter   8
Joe     4
Laura   3
Peter   50
Joe     80
Peter   70
Peter   80
Joe     40
Laura   30
Peter   700
Peter   800
Peter   7002
Peter   8002
Peter   7000
Peter   8000
Peter   7001
Peter   8001
Pater   50
Jae     80
Pater   70
Pater   80
Jae     40
Laura   30
```

The output is:

```
Peter   5
Peter   7
Peter   8
Peter   50
Peter   70
Peter   80
Peter   700
Peter   800
Peter   7002
Peter   8002
Peter   7000
Peter   8000
Peter   7001
Peter   8001
Joe     8
Joe     4
Joe     80
Joe     40
Laura   3
Laura   30
Laura   30
Pater   50
Pater   70
Pater   80
Jae     80
Jae     40
```

The `-k3,3` sort term is necessary for this data set; it sorts Laura's entries before Pater's entries (when omitted, you get those two lists interleaved).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one using awk:

> awk '{ a[ $1, ++b[$1] ]=$0 ; if(b[$1]>max) max=b[$1] }
>
> ```
>    END{ for(x=max;x>=1;x--)
>          for( k in b )
>            if( a[k,x] )
>               for(y=1;y<=x;y++) {
>                     print a[k,y]
>                     delete a[k,y]
>                }
>    }' filename
> ```

It works fine with gawk and POSIX awk. The presence of three loops in the END statement might affect performance with big files.